# Regular expressions return same duplicate answer

Tags: javascript, regex, return, instance

I am parsing out FortiGate logs with JavaScript regular expressions and am having some troubles with returning duplicate values.  Here is my string:

```
Jan 30 12:14:26 [23.4.56.4] date=2013-01-30,time=12:14:26,devname=FGT60C3G665236574,device_id=FGT60C3G665236574,log_id=0021000002,type=traffic,subtype=allowed,pri=notice,vd=root,src=10.10.89.107,src_port=59216,src_int=""internal"",dst=15.26.25.195,dst_port=53640,dst_int=""wan1"",SN=556987,status=accept,policyid=1,dir_disp=org,tran_disp=snat,proto=6,duration=120,sent=240,rcvd=238,sent_pkt=4,rcvd_pkt=3
```

I am using the following regular expression to get out the devname

```
/devname=(.*?),/
```

This is what is returned when I run the following code

```
var reDeviceName = /devname=(.*?),/;

var log3='Jan 30 12:14:26 [23.4.56.4] date=2013-01-30,time=12:14:26,devname=FGT60C3G665236574,device_id=FGT60C3G665236574,log_id=0021000002,type=traffic,subtype=allowed,pri=notice,vd=root,src=10.10.89.107,src_port=59216,src_int=""internal"",dst=15.26.25.195,dst_port=53640,dst_int=""wan1"",SN=556987,status=accept,policyid=1,dir_disp=org,tran_disp=snat,proto=6,duration=120,sent=240,rcvd=238,sent_pkt=4,rcvd_pkt=3';

console.log(log3.match(new RegExp(reDeviceName)));
```

This is what is returned:

```
 [0] => devname=FGT60C3G665236574
 [1] => devname=
 [2] => FGT60C3G665236574
```

How can I just return what is between 
devname=FGT60C3G665236574,

and just return one instance of the information FGT60C3G665236574

Comment: It returns `["devname=FGT60C3G665236574,", "FGT60C3G665236574"]`, which is fine, the first index contains always the full match, when you have capture groups they start at index 1.

Comment: What is the best way to just get FGT60C3G665236574?  As you see the index has 3 entries, how can I just have 1?

Comment: Your current code returns that array I posted above, try it. All you need to do is grab the 2nd index: http://jsbin.com/iSeYIRU/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
console.log(log3.match(new RegExp(reDeviceName))[1]);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n2tR/).

Note that the actual array doesn't have the first element you mentioned in your question.

Note that you can directly use:

```
var reDeviceName = /devname=(.*?),/;

var log3='Jan 30 12:14:26 [23.4.56.4] date=2013-01-30,time=12:14:26,devname=FGT60C3G665236574,device_id=FGT60C3G665236574,log_id=0021000002,type=traffic,subtype=allowed,pri=notice,vd=root,src=10.10.89.107,src_port=59216,src_int=""internal"",dst=15.26.25.195,dst_port=53640,dst_int=""wan1"",SN=556987,status=accept,policyid=1,dir_disp=org,tran_disp=snat,proto=6,duration=120,sent=240,rcvd=238,sent_pkt=4,rcvd_pkt=3';

console.log(log3.match(redeviceName)[1]);
```

[omitting the `new RegExp()` constructor]

Comment: There's no need to use `new RegExp` at all, anywhere in the code. The assignment `reDeviceName = /blah/` is already a `RegExp` instance.

Comment: @TedHopp Oh, sorry, I though it was a bit similar to python in that using the constructor function improves performance if the regexp has to be used multiple times. All good now.